# Mocking a custom node module using jest.mock method

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs

So, I am new to mocking a module using **jest.mock()**

So here is the scenario, I have created a node module and uploaded to the private npm registry from where I can that module in my app.

If suppose the name of the module is **@a/lp-mod** and if this the **index.js** of that module:

```
export const lpr = async () => {
    // some code that does something and returns some data back
}
export default {
   lpr
}
```

now let us all suppose I need to mock this module (@a/lp-mod) and have to return some static data whenever **lpr** function is gets called in the context of a test case.

So here is the code I have written:

```
> proj_directory
  |---->__mocks__
  |     |--->@a
  |     |     |--->lp-mod --> this directory has index.js with mock data
  |---->node_modules
  |     |--->@a
  |     |     |--->lp-mod --> this directory has index.js inside /src
  |     |          |---> src
  |     |     |          |---> index.js
  |---->test
  |     |--->1.test.js --->
```

**node_modules/@a/lp-mod/src/index.js**

```
// some npm imports like axios
export const lpr = async () => {
  // has some I/O calls, but let's just keep it simple
  return Promise.resolve('I am original call')
}
export default {
  lpr
}
```

**__mocks__/@a/lp-mod/index.js**

```
const p = jest.genMockFromModule('@a/lp-mod')
p.lpr = () => Promise.resolve('This is mocked call')
export default p
```

**1.test.js**

```
// before describe (test case) I wrote this
jest.mock('@a/lp-mod')
```

But I am getting **undefined** when the file is trying to import the original **@a/lp-mod** module for the usage inside the test context.

As per my expectation, it should get the mocked module and return the data from there only, if I am testing my app.

Please shed some light & bear with me incase some of the info is missing, please let me know in case there is any doubt.
Happy coding :)

Comment: your approach seems reasonable...can you show how you are importing `@a/lp-mod` into your test file?

Comment: actually my test file is not going to import that. the business logic is like, I am calling /writing the test case for the controller and internally controller imports service and service will finally import this custom node module @a/lp-mod. So my assumption is when internally this module is loaded then my mocked version will be returned instead of the original one, because as far as I understood the jest, the mocking is done as a global scope mocking and not the local stuff mocking, please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: that should work fine, how are you importing `@a/lp-mod` into your service?  (I'm trying to reproduce the issue but it's working fine for me)

Comment: Import { lpr} from '@a/lpr-mod'